# XML Order in Retrofit Body Class using org.simpleframework.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, retrofit

I am using a retrofit network controller to post a SOAP request. The @Body is using org.simpleframework.xml to generate the xml in a class. The class structure is as followed

```
 @Root(name = "soap:Envelope")

@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(prefix = "soap", reference = ""),
        @Namespace(prefix = "typ", reference = ""),
        @Namespace(prefix = "ldb", reference = "")
})


public class RequestEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soap:Header")
    RequestHeader requestHeader;

    public void setRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        this.requestHeader = requestHeader;
    }

    public RequestHeader getRequestHeader() {
        return requestHeader;
    }


    @Element(name = "soap:Body")
    RequestBody requestBody;


    public void setRequestBody(RequestBody requestBody) {
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
    }

    public RequestBody getRequestBody() {
        return requestBody;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the generated xml in the submitted body as the structure of the soap:Body first and then soap:Header. This is causing the api call to fail because it requires soap:Header to be first. I have tried to use `@Order(elements = {"soap:Header", "soap:Body"})`, but the app tells me that there is no elements labeled soap:Header or soap:Body in the class.

I have used this class with a single element before, but it seems to be having a problem with multiple elements. From what I can see, the return is ordered alphabetically.

Does anyone know how to stop the alphabetical order in the generated xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue in the past and YES, @Order annotations doesn't solve the problem. Funny enough... I solved the problem by changing the name of the variables to have alphabetical order, in my case I just added a "z" to the "body" (name of my variable), check my class and give it a Try.

```
@Root(name = "soap12:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace( prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "xsd", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "soap12", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
})

public class CardSaleRequestEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soap12:Header", required = true)
    private CardSaleRequestHeader header;

    @Element(name = "soap12:Body", required = true)
    private ZCardSaleRequestBody zbody;

    public CardSaleRequestEnvelope() {
    }


    public CardSaleRequestHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(CardSaleRequestHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public ZCardSaleRequestBody getBody() {
        return zbody;
    }

    public void setBody(ZCardSaleRequestBody zbody) {
        this.zbody = zbody;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a working solution which lets you keep your variables' names, but you have to use `@Namespace(reference)` for prefixes instead of `@Element(name)`. I know it doesn't look very clean and you'd guess `@Namespace(prefix)` would work too - it wouldn't.

```
@Root(name = "soap:Envelope", strict = false)
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
                prefix = "soap")
})
@Order(elements = {"Header", "Body"})
public class LoginRequest {

    @Element(name = "Header")
    @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
    public Header header;

    @Element(name = "Body")
    @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
    public Body body;

    public LoginRequest() {
    }

    ...
}
```

Sources:

- http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the wrong syntax.
you can try:

```
@Root(name = "soap:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(prefix = "soap", reference = ""),
        @Namespace(prefix = "typ", reference = ""),
        @Namespace(prefix = "ldb", reference = "")
})

@Order(elements = {"soap:Envelope/soap:Header", "soap:Envelope/soap:Body"})

public class RequestEnvelope {

@Element(name = "soap:Header")
RequestHeader requestHeader;

public void setRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader) {
    this.requestHeader = requestHeader;
}

public RequestHeader getRequestHeader() {
    return requestHeader;
}


@Element(name = "soap:Body")
RequestBody requestBody;


public void setRequestBody(RequestBody requestBody) {
    this.requestBody = requestBody;
}

public RequestBody getRequestBody() {
    return requestBody;
}
}
```